# kitchen corner cabinet with sink has wasted space inside, looking for workarounds to salvage the lost space?

Tags: kitchens, cabinets, kitchen-counters

I have ordered custom made kitchen cabinets. The corner location was awkward for the design, also I got the wrong sink for this application in hindsight (36" Apron sink).
When the carpenter got the sink, he designed the main cabinet such that the sink sits in it since that's the proper way for this sink installation.
However, there is a considerable volume in the cabinets that would not be utilized as the space would be closed from all sides, these are shown in the picture marked in red boxes below.
The carpenter mentioned that he could open small rectangles inside on the lower left and and right sides of the middle cabinet, but that has limitations as the hole cannot be big to preserve the integrity of the structure as it will bear a heavy weight.
I'm already running low on space and was curious if there are any other potential workarounds that could still be done to salvage this space? Countertop is not installed yet.
Thank you for your suggestions. [image]

Comment: I am flagging it as decoration question.

Comment: Well, I guess now you know why they don't do this. You also wasted huge amount of space behind the sink because you can't reach back there on the counter.

Comment: You're in a tough spot.  If the sink wasn't there, there might be things you could do to access the space, but the sink really needs the support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a similar situation in my home. The cabinet needs to be rebuilt such that it is not a rectangular box. The cabinet should be built to match the shape of the available space and support beams crossing the upper interior of the cabinet can be used to support the sink. Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is extremely unlikely that there is an inexpensive solution for it.  In a similar situation, look at what's on the other side of the wall.

In one house, I put in cupboards in the other room to use the space.  In the current house it was the media room, so I put the woofer in that space with a grill in front.